# perl 'last' statement and variable scope

Tags: perl, loops, break

Should-be simple Perl construction is not behaving as I expect.

The `@closest` array holds strings of the form "NNN-NNN". I am trying to find the first array element where the initial "NNN" matches a specific value.

Since I have declared `$compoundKey` outside the loop, I expect it to be persistent. The loop behaves as expected, exiting when I get a match. However, after the code exits the loop, the `$compoundKey` variable is empty. (See log output after code. I am looking for "83". The matched element is not the last element in the array.)

```
    my $compoundKey;
    foreach $compoundKey (@closest)
    {
        logentry("In loop compoundKey is $compoundKey\n");
        last if ($compoundKey =~ /^$RID/);   
    }
    logentry("Outside loop compoundKey is $compoundKey\n");
```

Log file:

```
    2019-02-27 18:15:26: In loop compoundKey is 90-1287
    2019-02-27 18:15:26: In loop compoundKey is 86-1223
    2019-02-27 18:15:26: In loop compoundKey is 86-1235
    2019-02-27 18:15:26: In loop compoundKey is 87-1316
    2019-02-27 18:15:26: In loop compoundKey is 89-1219
    2019-02-27 18:15:26: In loop compoundKey is 83-1224
    2019-02-27 18:15:26: Outside loop compoundKey is
```

I assume I can fix this by doing an explicit assignment of a temporary loop variable to `$compoundKey`, but I'm still somewhat mystified. Is there some bug in my code that I am not seeing? Or does the "last" statement in Perl behave in a totally different way than "break" in C or Java?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course I am using "strict".

Comment: Also see [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) with the whole range of its [search](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#Searching) methods, eg `firstval` and `firstidx`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the `last` statement, [it's the `foreach` statement](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops).

> The foreach loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the scalar variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn. If the variable is preceded with the keyword my, then it is lexically scoped, and is therefore visible only within the loop. **Otherwise, the variable is implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting the loop.** If the variable was previously declared with my, it uses that variable instead of the global one, but it's still localized to the loop. This implicit localization occurs only in a foreach loop. (Emphasis added).

Comment: Seems counter-intuitive, but I won't make this mistake again!

Comment: The easiest way to avoid this problem is to always use loop-lexical iterators (`foreach my $foo`). Assign separately to a variable declared outside if you want to save a value.